# Can a manager kick you out for being trans in North Carolina

Tags: united-states, north-carolina, transgender

36 minutes ago
They kicked me out for being trans and going to my preferred bathroom. I get not using the lady's restroom if I had a big beard but I don't have a beard I wasn't doing anything in there but fixing my hair and makeup

Comment: It doesn't matter whether someone "looks like a lady". Transwomen are women and have exactly the same right to use the women's bathroom, whether they have boobs, beards, or neither.

Comment: @Nij That approach renders it completely useless to have separate bathrooms for males and females because anyone would be able to claim they're one or the other at any time. The division exists to avoid people feeling uncomfortable in the presence of persons that they _perceive_ to be of the opposite sex, no matter what those identify themselves.

Comment: "anyone would be able to claim they're one or the other at any time" - yes, they would. And if someone had a problem with it, the judicial system exists to establish whether that problem is reasonable and legitimate. Not for people to assert themselves the sole arbiter of who is and is not A Real Woman.

Comment: @Nij The judicial system would act in the public interests here. If a dozen of ladies say "That's a man — I don't want to see him in female bathroom!", the court won't accept the trans' claim that they're a lady too for the purposes of being allowed in there (let alone such a claim of a dude with a beard).

Comment: law.SE is not a place to debate what we think about transgender public bathroom use.  It is a place to discuss the laws involved with it.

Answer (score 6):

It is not presently illegal for a private property owner in North Carolina to impose such a requirement on restroom users.

Comment: Isn't NC actually one of the states where trans people are _legally forbidden_ from using the correct restrooms?